# react-native-google-signin/google-signin additon of scopes results in infinte loading

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I am trying to get token so that i can upload videos to youtube. for this i started using

```
import {
    GoogleSignin,
    GoogleSigninButton,
    statusCodes,
  } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
```

scopes are taken from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

But if you try adding any scope like the code below it results in infinite loading, it does not even time out eg code:

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
             scopes: [//'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
                    //'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
                ],
            webClientId: 'webClientId', 
          });
```

what works is defaults scope and the code looks like this:

```
GoogleSignin.configure({webClientId: 'webClientId',  });
```

and the response from the server is  with two scopes

```
[
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
]
```

Any help to get token scope with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube would be greatly appreciated.

react-native: 0.64.2
npm : 7.19.1
eact-native-google-signin/google-signin: 7.0.0-alpha.3

**Update: solution**

go to : https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
Please change OAuth consent screen -> Publishing status to Testing(Click BACK TOTESTING) and Then add Test users

By default you wont be able to see it, look at the attached screenshot to see the different screens
[image]

[image]

Comment: i have added the solution with images in question itself please check